# How to save GLSurfaceView to texture/buffer/bitmap

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, bitmap

I'm developing application for Android with GLSurfaceView. One moment i have to replace my GLSurfaceView with an image of it in that moment. The question is, how to get an image right? I used this code:

```
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(500, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(500, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
    v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());

    v.buildDrawingCache(true);
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache
    return b;
```

but it always return black bitmap.

Maybe we can make something other then Bitmap (which also can be placed to GLSurfaceView)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it works this way with a `GLSurfaceView`. The framebuffer may live inside the GPU, where it's not directly accessible on the CPU.

You can use a [framebuffer object](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) to render the image to a texture, then use `glReadPixels` to download the data into a buffer and turn the buffer into a `Bitmap`.

Comment: Hi Thomas, Thanks you for your answer. can u please suggest any sample codes or links..

Comment: @Thomas I am doing same thing to save bitmap. But I want to get only Bitmap portion, other part of that GLSurfaceView. How to do that?

Comment: Please open a new question for that, if it's different from the one asked here.

Answer (score 0):

Save GLSurfaceView to bitmap. Its working Correct.

```
MyRenderer Class :

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {


try {
    int w = width_surface ;
    int h = height_surface  ;

    Log.i("hari", "w:"+w+"-----h:"+h);

    int b[]=new int[(int) (w*h)];
    int bt[]=new int[(int) (w*h)];
    IntBuffer buffer=IntBuffer.wrap(b);
    buffer.position(0);
    GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h,GLES20.GL_RGBA,GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
    for(int i=0; i<h; i++)
    {
         //remember, that OpenGL bitmap is incompatible with Android bitmap
         //and so, some correction need.        
         for(int j=0; j<w; j++)
         {
              int pix=b[i*w+j];
              int pb=(pix>>16)&0xff;
              int pr=(pix<<16)&0x00ff0000;
              int pix1=(pix&0xff00ff00) | pr | pb;
              bt[(h-i-1)*w+j]=pix1;
         }
    }           
    Bitmap inBitmap = null ;
    if (inBitmap == null || !inBitmap.isMutable()
         || inBitmap.getWidth() != w || inBitmap.getHeight() != h) {
        inBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }
    //Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    inBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
    //return inBitmap ;
    // return Bitmap.createBitmap(bt, w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    inBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bt, w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
    inBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bos); 
    byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
    ByteArrayInputStream fis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bitmapdata);

    final Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
     long mytimestamp=c.getTimeInMillis();
    String timeStamp=String.valueOf(mytimestamp);
    String myfile="hari"+timeStamp+".jpeg";

    dir_image=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+
             "printerscreenshots"+File.separator+"image");
    dir_image.mkdirs();

    try {
        File tmpFile = new File(dir_image,myfile); 
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = fis.read(buf)) > 0) {
            fos.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        fis.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

       Log.v("hari", "screenshots:"+dir_image.toString());

    }
}catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace() ;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and format the code to make it readable

Comment: @harikrishnan your code works fine to save the GLSurfaceView as bitmap. But i want to save like only bitmap that I am displaying on that surfaceview.